# Particula string search in python

Tags: python, string

```
if 'bl1' in open('/tmp/ch.py').read():
        print 'OK'
```

I have to search for the particular string `"bl1"`.
Any way to get it?

I tried using `^bl1$` , it didn't work.

Comment: starting(^) and ending($)...I want to do exact string search

Comment: have you tried looping over each line to and then each word?

Comment: Yes, it works but I want to have the exact match of this string..I can say...bl1 is present in 'asfdbl1' and 'bl123'..it should not match this.

Comment: what do you mean the exact match?

Comment: you mean an individual word?

Comment: If you find it, what do you want to happen?

Comment: I would use with to open the file then loop over each line splitting and checking each line

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply running a verification to confirm "bl1" appears in the text of the file, I think your statement is OK. It have tested and the if statement returned True (given that ch.py has words containing 'bl1' inside)...

```
if 'bl1' in open('/tmp/ch.py').read():
    print 'OK'

>>> if 'bl1' in open('/tmp/ch.py').read():
...     print("ok")
...
ok

>>> if 'bl1' in "dfdsaflj hjjfadsfbl1dafdsfd bl1llll bdasbl1aa":
...     print("ok")
...
ok
```

Reading from you saying '^bl1$', I assume you are trying to apply regular expression, but unfortunately you didn't follow the rules of regular expression explicitly.

If you are looking to extract the words containing the 3 consecutive characters 'bl1', you can apply the built-in function from re module.

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.findall('\w+[bl1]\w+', open('/tmp/ch.py').read())  // finds all occurrences 
>>> match
['asfdbl1', 'bl123']    // return all occurrences of words containing 'bl1' in a list
```

As in your format, it should look like this:

```
>>> if re.findall('\w+[bl1]\w+', open('/tmp/ch.py').read()):
...     print('OK')
...
OK
>>>
```

In regular expression, '^bl1$' is the format to look one match in a string that starts with "bl1" and ends with "bl1", which means the whole string has to be 'bl1' exactly for a matching..

```
>>> match = re.findall('^bl1$', open('/tmp/ch.py').read())
>>> match
[]
>>> match = re.findall('^bl1$', 'bl1')    // exactly "bl1"
>>> match
['bl1']
>>> match = re.findall('^bl1$', 'bl12')    // not exactly "bl1"
>>> match
[]
```

If you are interested in regular expression, I hope you can find what you like in the documentation of Python standard libraries - re : https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html